# watson data refinery Date column operation

Tags: watson, watson-studio, ibm-data-refinery

I am using  IBM watson data refine project and added my csv file having date column say 'joining date'. Now I want to add another column'last day of week' which will have date for Friday of the  'joining date' week. Also, I  want to add another column which will have number of working days in a week i.e 'last day of week' - 'joining date'. 
I cant find any operations for date  in refine project so that I can calculate day of week etc. What else way I could use to refine data using IBM cloud and/or watson service.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarise, in your input data you intend to have this column:

Joining Date

From that date column you want Data Refinery to generate two new date columns:

1. Last Day of the Week - The date of each Friday in each week found in the "Joining Date" column
2. Number of Working Days - The difference between each of the dates found in "Joining Date" and "Number of Working Days"

Is that correct?

Also, could you clarify your final question, I'm unsure what specifically you're asking?

Regards,

Wesley - IBM Watson Data Refinery

Comment: Hi wesley, that is correct. currently I am unable to do any operation on my input column 'joining Date' . My main aim is to calculate the date of friday of the week where 'joining date' exists. Thanks.Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Also I am not sure if Watson Data Refinery currently supports date operations as while selecting  Date column most of the given operations asks to change column. Didnt got any specific operation  for Date like DOW in sql. So wanted to ask if data refinery is right service for my needs or there is some other service in watson / ibm cloud which could help here